# When to use 今現在 instead of 今 or 現在?

Tags: meaning

I came across the word 今現在 and I can't figure out when to use it. I found out it [means](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%BB%8A%E7%8F%BE%E5%9C%A8) "just now; at this moment; at this point of time" but this information doesn't really help me understand when to use it instead of 今 or 現在.

I am (somewhat) aware of the difference between 今 and 現在. Both refer to the present time and can overlap in their usage in some cases, being 今 the closer to "now" in terms of "the immediate time physically speaking" and 現在 closer to "the present time", "currently as opposed to the past or the future".　While I might be inaccurate or even outright wrong in my understanding of both words, at least I have some difference I can rely on when trying to decide when to use one or the other, but with 今現在 I am lost.

I found the word in the book N2新完全マスター page 4, in the section 問題紹介:

> よく、「自分が本当にやりたいことをみつけなければならない」と、あたかもそれが動力すれば必ずみつかるもののように語られ、プレッシャーを感じる人も多いと思いますが、私はそれがみつかるかどうかは、極端にいって「運」しだいだと思います。だから、**今現在** 、それがみつかっていない**から**といって、焦ることも、自己嫌悪に陥ることもありません。

---

I am also probably missing some crucial information related to this から bit that I highlighted that makes the sentence more confusing to me. I just parsed the sentence skipping this から in the following way to try to understand it:

> だから、**今現在** 、それがみつかっていない**<s>から</s>**といって[**も**]、焦ることも、自己嫌悪に陥ることもありません。

For this reason, だから

even if といって[も]

I haven't found this それがみつかっていない

at this moment, 今現在

it's not the case that こともありません

I fret 焦る

or I’ve fallen into self-hatred 自己嫌悪に陥る.

---

When is 今現在 preferable to 今 and 現在?　Could 今現在 be replaced by 今 or 現在 in the provided context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a longer and thus more emphatic version of 今. It's one of the words used when you want something stronger than "now". It's like "right at this moment". Semantically, I think 今現在 is much closer to 今 than to 現在.